# How to gpg verify my bitcoin core download step by step on ubuntu server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, verification, installation

I am a newbie when it comes to setting up a bitcoin node but I am trying to gpg verify my bitcoin core download the pub keys to do so are no longer available. I have tried doing my own research but I can't seem to find someone to explain in Layman's terms how to do so now.

I have downloaded all three files needed to do so:

```
bitcoin-24.0.1-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
SHA256SUMS 
SHA256SUMS.asc
```

I have verified the checksum of the release file

```
sha256sum --ignore-missing --check SHA256SUMS
```

Now I am totally lost on what to do from here because the txt file is not on GitHub anymore. I have been trying to figure this out for a while now but can't seem to do so. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The builder keys file has moved to a [different repository](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/tree/main/builder-keys). The [download verification instructions](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/#verify-your-download) on the bitcoincore.org website were updated. Follow the steps detailed there to verify your Bitcoin Core download.

Answer (score 1):

gpg --list-keys

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/main/builder-keys/achow101.gpg

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/main/builder-keys/benthecarman.gpg

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/main/builder-keys/fanquake.gpg

gpg --import achow101.gpg

gpg --import benthecarman.gpg

gpg --import fanquake.gpg

gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.asc

Answer (score -1):

You'll just have to follow the steps listed at

https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/

But essentially, you're doing it right, downloading those three files and then running sha256sum returns the following:

```
$ sha256sum --ignore-missing --check SHA256SUMS
bitcoin-24.0.1-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz: OK
```

Comment: So I don't need to get public keys anymore and verify it? Cause when I follow the instructions the rest doesn't make sense cause of missing pages on GitHub.

Comment: Not really sure what steps are you following. The official documentation is the one I linked to on my original answer.

Comment: This answer seems to be missing most of the point.

Comment: That's verifying the checksums match, bit is missing the gpg verification of the checksum file's authrnticity